# Remove part of Gameobject name

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to remove a part of a name given to a GameObject? For instance:

Im instantiating gameobjects for the use of bullets. I give them the name of the player shooting the bullet. So if a player's name is "Ben", his bullets are called Ben's bullet.

```
gameObject.name = playerName + "'s bullet";
```

Now I'm trying to use this name to know wich person gives the finishing blow to an other player. And to do this I want find the player object with the same name as the bullet, and update his kill count. So I want to remove the "'s bullet" part from the bullets name.

So long story short: Is it possible to remove a part of a name given to a GameObject?

Hope that this is clear enough en help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit: This is the part where the name has to change:

```
if(other.gameObject.tag == "bullet"){

         var colBullet = other.transform.name;
         playerHealth = playerHealth - 5;

         if(playerHealth <= 0){
          onDie();
          //colBullet = colBullet - "'s bullet";
          GameObject.Find(colBullet);
         }       }
```

The name of the collided object is put in the colBullet variable. I printed it and it says: Playername's bullet. This works but now the only thing it needs is the 's bullet being removed

Comment: This question is better suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. Consider posting future game related stuff there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int suffixLength = "'s bullet".Length;
string player = gameObject.name.Substring(0, gameObject.name.Length - suffixLength);
```

But maybe it would be better to have a property that doesn't need manipulating to find the player name?

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: keep a reference to the player in your GameObject, instead of its name. This way you save on look ups for the player if you want to, for example, increase the experience or gold the shooter has for each kill. For stray bullets, or recycled ones, just set Player to null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Replace() function to remove the part you want, like this:

```
gameObject.name = gameObject.name.Replace("s bullet", "");
```